# Magento 2 - Get configuratble product using API

Tags: magento2, api

I can get product detail with this API endpoint:

> https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=16901

But when I am getting **configurable product** using this API then I am getting product details without **configurations/variations**

Is there another way to get configurable product with it's variations?